# ¿Es correcto votar en contra si una respuesta a tu parecer es muy mala a pesar del esfuerzo?

Tags: discusión, respuesta, votos, votos-negativos

Hace poco voté en contra de una repuesta que "funcionaba" con varias limitantes pero en mi parecer era simplemente mala.

Dejemos un ejemplo similar, donde se pide que se sumen `n` números en un método en java:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese cuántos números va a sumar");
        // Se usa para leer entradas desde consola
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        // Se usa para leer números
        int n = scanner.nextInt();
        int[] numbers = new int[n];
        // llenando el arreglo
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el número " + (i + 1));
            numbers[i] = scanner.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println(sumNumbers(numbers));
    }

    public static int sumNumbers(int n, int... numbers) {
        int sum = 0;
        boolean sirve = false;

        switch (n){
            case 1:
                if (numbers.length == n) {
                    sirve = true;
                    sum = numbers[0];
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                if (numbers.length == n) {
                    sirve = true;
                    sum = numbers[0] + numbers[1];
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if (numbers.length == n) {
                    sirve = true;
                    sum = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2];
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if (numbers.length == n) {
                    sirve = true;
                    sum = numbers[0] + numbers[1] + numbers[2] + numbers[3];
                }
                break;
        }
        if (!sirve) {
            System.out.println("No se pudo sumar");
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Mis criterios para votar en contra fueron:

- La respuesta está limitada a que `n <= 4` cuando lo correcto debería ser para cualquier caso
- La respuesta incluye más elementos de los necesarios, pues sólo pregunta por el método y mete más código del necesario
- Realmente la solución complicaba más el problema y no funcionaba en la mayoría de los casos, pues muy probablemente `n > 4`
- En el artículo de [votar negativo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) mencionan:

> La emisión de votos negativos, también conocida como "votar en contra", es la forma en la que la comunidad indica qué preguntas y respuestas son menos útiles.

El autor preguntó los motivos por los que se había votado negativamente a su respuesta para así poder mejorarla, al comentar mis motivos, el autor expuso que había escrito su respuesta con su esfuerzo y conocimientos, lo que provocó que recibiera bastantes críticas, "odio", e incluso votos negativos en mi respuesta (que creo que no son correctos, pues parecen ser como en señal de venganza). Lo cual me dejó pensando si es en realidad malo hacer este tipo de votos.

Como tal cada quién tiene diferentes niveles de conocimiento y cada uno tiene el derecho a contribuir a la comunidad, por lo cual a veces me da un poco de pena votar negativamente a estas respuestas pero, a mi parecer, sí era de baja calidad la respuesta, ya que creo firmemente que programar no sólo se trata de codificar, sino de pensar y analizar los problemas para hallar buenas soluciones.

El autor se lo tomó bien, pero otros miembros de la comunidad no.

Comment: Si la respuesta es mala, definitivamente Si. También a veces creamos respuestas de gran esfuerzo, sin mucho valor, cuando somos novatos y queremos resolver todo el problema del OP. Yo tengo respuestas que son básicamente el proyecto del OP y no tienen ningún voto a favor (y con justa razón). Pienso que, en ese caso, la mejor posición sería no votar en contra, si no decírselo, ya que con el tiempo uno va aprendiendo que esto no es "el rincón del vago" y los votos negativos probablemente se mal-interpreten que los experimentados tratan de forma hostil a los nuevos.

Comment: Pues el usuario no es tan nuevo, tiene más reputación que yo... Eso también me influenció a el voto negativo

Comment: Las respuestas malas no aportan. Para mi es correcto votarla negativo. Poner una respuesta, tambien implica un trabajo comprobarla y asegurarse que sirva. Esa respuesta no sirve para n > 4, con lo cual es dudoso que le enseñe a alguien como sumar mas de esa cantidad de caracteres. No hay forma de que esa respuesta tenga ni un voto positivo.. seria un ejercicio mal resuelto hasta para alguien que esta aprendiendo..

Comment: @EduardoJiménez En SO se debe analizar la publicación, no votamos por personas sino por la calidad de la publicación. Asi que si la pregunta es mala entonces dale un DV, si no cumple con las reglas del sitio vota por cerrarlas o levanta una bandera.

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Tú dices: *El autor se lo tomó bien, pero otros miembros de la comunidad no.*, ¿como se dieron cuenta de tu voto? El voto en SO es secreto ya que justamente ello nos da la libertad de juzgar la calidad de las publicaciones sin pensar en que tendremos represalias.

Comment: @eyllanesc porque el autor preguntó sobre el motivo de los votos negativos para mejorar entonces su respuesta. Comenté mis motivos y el expuso que lo había hecho con su esfuerzo y conocimientos, lo que de alguna manera hizo que otros integrantes vieran mal mi downvote. Pero bueno, creo que ya se calmó el asunto. !Gracias!

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Los comentarios que piden ese tipo información son solo ruido, mi recomendación es que nunca señales que distes un voto a favor o en contra sino que señalale que probablemente por el motivo X o Y su pregunta no cumple con los requerimientos del sitio. No indiques nada acerca de los votos ya que no aportan nada a la discusión y solo traen más problemas que beneficios.

Comment: Gracias, lo tomaré muy en cuenta la siguiente vez

Comment: @EduardoJiménez El objetivo de los comentarios es discutir de como mejorar la publicación, pedir información, sugerir cambios, etc. No sirven para discutir temas ajenos como los votos. La idea es reorientar su atención a la calidad de su post que a los votos. Nota: Si ves comentarios que dicen: *¿por que me dieron el DV?* solo levanta una bandera para que lo eliminen ya que no aportan nada, son una distracción.

Comment: @eyllanesc cada vez que emito un voto en contra explico la razón del porqué lo hice, nunca he tenido un problema como esto. Creo que siempre es bueno dejar un comentario de la razón, de esa forma el autor sabe las carencias de su publicación y las puede editar y si la edición mejora la respuesta se retrae el voto en contra. Fácil y sencillo

Comment: Imaginemos esto en el caso de Python, una regla es que debes de escribir el menor código siempre que sea posible, cuando recién inicias te es muy difícil imaginar una forma simplificada de escribir un `for`. Esto significa que las respuestas que tengan bastante código (que puede simplificarse) deban ser votadas en contra??

Comment: @Christian Bueno, esa es tu decisión y propia experiencia que afortunadamente no has tenido insultos ni represalias pero no es la experiencia de todos desgraciadamente. En SOen la regla es clara: No es obligatorio motivar tus votos, no es productivo discutir sobre los votos en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola Eduardo, el usuario al cual votaste negativo no era nuevo, la respuesta era algo limitada. Recuerdo en alguna ocasión realice una respuesta la cual era una solución muy limitada, no escalable, y alguien me comento que no era lo recomendable ya que tenía más conocimiento que yo y voto en contra lo cual ahora considero válido ya que ahora conociendo un poco más de ese lenguaje no es una respuesta que daría actualmente. Como dice Gonzalo "Las respuestas malas no aportan.", estoy de acuerdo.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

En esta página no se mide el esfuerzo, se mide el conocimiento. En otras palabras: la puntuación no es un reflejo de lo que creemos que se ha esforzado el autor, si no de los conocimientos que es capaz de transmitir.

Lo que debe preocuparte de una respuesta es:

- ¿Responde a la pregunta?
- ¿Resuelve las dudas del autor de la pregunta?
- ¿Ayuda al autor de la pregunta (y, sobre todo, a otros futuros lectores)?

Imagina no tener conocimiento alguno y llegar a una respuesta "mala pero con mucho esfuerzo", si esa respuesta no responde a los puntos anteriores, por mucho esfuerzo que se le haya dedicado estará haciendo más mal que bien.